# Why is the value of 'i' in the loop not conflicting with the one initialized in the for loop

Tags: c, loops

The value of `i` is not conflicting with the value of `i` initialized inside the loop, why is it so?

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
        int i = 10;
        printf("%d \t", i);
        i--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why should it? The `i` of the for loop is simply shadowed by the `i` inside the braces.

Comment: Study "scope" in your C book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `i` was initialized as zero in the loop. Now, when the loop iteration begins, the identically named variable `i` inside the braces shadows the original one (defined outside of the braces).

Since it was initialized to 10, the program displays `10`, then it is decremented by one later that doesn't affect the output because the shadowed `int i = 10;` is executed in each iteration. This will keep happening 5 times.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ndYTqM).

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to know that how is the compiler able to keep a record for two-variable with the same name but different values, at perhaps two different memory locations. Basically, why is the value of i = 2 not 9 the second time it enters the loop, thereby not going in an infinite loop?

Comment: @UtkarshSingh It's because – in every iteration, the shadowed `int i = 10;` is executed.

Comment: @UtkarshSingh It's all about scopes of the variables. Suppose a variable `int var = 10`, and you redefine another variable inside an independent `{}` – this is called a variable *shadows the original one*. Any code outside the braces will use the original `var`.

Comment: @UtkarshSingh Take a look into a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ndYTqM).